# No natural log parentheses when typesetting

Tags: typography, parentheses

How can I insert parentheses around the content of the natural log? I want my document to show

ln(x+1)

but the code

```
\ln{x+1}
```

or

```
\ln(x+1)
```

or

```
\ln \left( x+1 \right)
```

will not produce this.

Edit:
I should have specified that this issue was occurring in an `equation` (math mode).

Earlier today I was having some issues compiling due to corrupt temporary files (log and aux files) but never restarted my tex environment. Upon rebooting this evening, my original document is placing parentheses as expected.

I am marking Christian's post as the solution due to his effort and his explanation really clears up what the command \ln actually is (a comand without an argument).

Thank you all for your quick responses.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With `$\ln(x+1)$` you surely get what you want.

Comment: `\ln` is an operator typeset command and does have an argument, i.e. `\ln{x+1}` works because `{...}` is not used as an argument here. Anyway, `\ln` does not typeset the parentheses

Comment: Really? `\ln(x+1)` does not produce the desired results?  If it does not , please post an image of what it does produce?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Restarting my tex environment has resolved the issue and '\ln(x+1)' does yield the expected results.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are some possibilities to achieve this, but all of them require entering into math mode, i.e. with `$...$`, `\(...\)`,  or `\[...\]` or one of the various math environments such as `equation` and `align`.

But `\ln{x+1}` is not producing a pair of parentheses. In fact, it's the same as `\ln x+1`. `\ln` is an command without arguments, so `\ln` stands alone actually and ignores the following `{...}`.

If the parentheses are required in many occasions,  wrapper macros, say `\lnn` and `\lnb` are useful, which uses either `\left(...\right)` or the medium spaced version `\mleft(...\mright)`, both of which has the advantage of `growing` parenthesis for fractions etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\newcommand{\lnn}[1]{%
  \ln\left(#1\right)%
}

\newcommand{\lnb}[1]{%
  \ln\mleft(#1\mright)%
}

\begin{document}


\verb!$\ln x+1$ and $\ln{x+1}$ produce the same output!

\begin{center}
  \fboxsep=0pt
  \fbox{$\ln x+1$}

  \fbox{$\ln{x+1}$}
\end{center}

produce the same output

With parentheses:

$
\begin{array}{ccc}
  \verb!\ln(x+1)! & \verb!\ln \left(x+1\right)! & \verb!\ln \mleft(x+1\mright)! \\
  \\
  \ln (x+1) & \ln \left(x+1\right) & \ln \mleft(x+1\mright) \\
  \\
   \verb!\lnb{x+1}! & \verb!\lnb{\dfrac{x+1}{x-1}}! & \verb+\lnn{n!}+\\
   \\
  \lnb{x+1} & \lnb{\dfrac{x+1}{x-1}} & \lnn{n!} \\
\end{array}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You may also want to point out that a common typographical convention -- which, naturally, is implemented by TeX -- posits that there should be *no whitespace* between a math operator (such as `\ln`, `\cos`, and `\det`) and a subsequent opening parenthesis (or, more generally, a math atom of type "math open"). Hence, `\ln\mleft(...` and `\lnb{...}` produce the typographically preferred look, whereas `\ln\left(...` and `\lnn{...}` do not.

Comment: And it should be noted that `\ln\mleft(x+1\mright)` is just a waste of tokens and keys, because the result differs in *no* way from the simpler `\ln(x+1)`.

Comment: @egreg: I can remember times you 'attacked' me for not using `\mleft...` ;-)

Comment: *If* you have to use automatic scalable fences, then `\mleft` and `\mright` are better than `\left` and `\right`. But in the case of `\ln(x+1)` there is no need whatsoever; worse, `\ln\mleft(x^2+1\mright)` might give too big parentheses than needed.

Comment: @egreg: Well, I keep it this way. It's up to the OP, which style he prefers.

Answer (score 0):

The `physics` package automatically produces `log()` and `ln()` with parentheses of the correct size. Just use

```
\usepackage{physics}
```

and `$log(x+1)$` and `$\log(\dfrac{x+1}{x-1})$` will work out-of-the-box.